# Binding a Property Value to the Label.Text VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to bind a property to a Label in VB.Net. Not data from a database, just a simple text value. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and I have the properties Getter and Setters defined. On the main UI I display the version in a Label like this.

First INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
```

In my form load I have

```
lblVersion.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Version")
lblProcess.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Process")
```

lblVersion works fine, but it is static. lblProcess changes and throws a cross thread error. "Control 'lblProcess' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Please help me get over the barrier here.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be a stretch to say the source of your problem may not actually be anything to with the INotifyPropertyChanged or binding but in fact where/how you're setting the value  of the Process property?

Comment: What is `Me` here? The Form? Have you added these properties to the Form itself? How do you set these properties? Where are the values of these properties coming from?

Comment: As the error message suggests, you cannot access members of a control on other than the UI thread. If those properties are members of the form then you shouldn't really be setting them on a secondary thread to start with. If you insist on doing so then your `RaisePropertyChanged` method should marshal to the UI thread before raising the event.

Comment: Hursey- In the case of the first exception it is when I set the property ("Process=SomeString")  in the main form where the property exists. Remember, the previous line works for the Version property. Jimi - Me is the main form where the property is defined. As I show in the OP the properties are set with Property=PopertyValue. Thanks jmcilhinney.

Comment: And there isn't anywhere else where that process property is set?  I'm leaning towards what @jmcilhinney is saying, something outside the intended scope is re-setting it, possibly unexpectedly, from another thread

Comment: You should use a class object, bound to a BindingSource. It's still not clear where/when/how these properties are set (this is what matters, here).

Comment: I agree with @Jimi that those properties should not be members of the form itself but rather some object that represents the data they contain. Even then though, you're still going to end up with a cross-thread error if you set them in the same place because that occurs when the `Binding` objects created by your second code snippet try to set the `Text` properties of those `Labels` on a secondary thread. The issue is not the binding. It's the setting of bound properties on a secondary thread. As I said, you need to marshal to the UI thread somewhere before raising the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: Jimi and jmcilhinney, thank you for your responses. The version property is set in the Form-Load event.  The Process property is set within methods called from a Timer Elapsed event. I think that is the problem. The methods are called from within the Elapsed event which appears to be a separate thread.  I have to move the code out of the event and figure out how to make the event trigger the work without it being in that thread. Then the properties are in the same thread as the methods where the value is set.